# Trouble figuring out Javascript & operator

Tags: javascript

So I am new to Javascript, in my first Intro to Javascript class. I just found what the `&` operator does and came across this definition:

> The & operator returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of both operands are ones.

I was also able to find descriptions of `==` and `===` on this website on a question that has been previously answered. On this link here: [Wikipedia Bitwise_operation#AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

It explains that `1 & 1` is the same as `1 x 1`, simple multiplication. So my question is then why is `10 & 5 == 0` and `10 & 6 == 2`

Wouldn't it be `10 & 5 == 50` and `10 & 6 == 60`?

What am I failing to understand?

Comment: You missed the whole "bits" part. A bit can only have the value 0 or 1, not 10 or 5.

Comment: It's `0b1010 & 0b0101 == 0b0000`. (10 and 5 in decimal notation). They are multiplied **bitwise**, for each bit index individually.

Answer (score 2):

It's only the binary bits in each position (the 1s and 0s) that are multiplied.

For example, with `10 & 5`:

10 = 1010 in binary

5 = 0101 in binary

Now multiply each digit against the other digit in the same position:

(1 x 0) (0 x 1) (1 x 0) (0 x 1)

= 0000

= 0 in decimal

```js
console.log(10 & 5)
```

With `10 & 6`:

10 = 1010 in binary

6 = 0110 in binary

Now multiply each digit against the other digit in the same position:

(1 x 0) (0 x 1) (1 x 1) (0 x 0)

= 0010

= 2 in decimal

```js
console.log(10 & 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s equivalent to multiplication *per bit*.

```
0 & 0 === 0
0 & 1 === 0
1 & 1 === 1
```

So your example of 10 & 5 is:

```
  1010
& 0101
= 0000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switch from base 10 to base 2, which is required when comparing numbers bitwise, then it is clearer :

> 10 & 5 becomes 1010 & 0101 which equals 0000 in base 2, 0 in base 10
>
> 10 & 6 becomes 1010 & 0110 which equals 0010 in base 2, 2 in base 10

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

So 10 should be something like this `1010` 
and 5 should be something like this `0101`

Now, if you find **& or And** for both of them, You should get something like `0000` which is zero

Similarly for 6, it should be `0110`

which should give **& or And** for both of them as `0010` which happens to be 2

Note: *for And we have the following rule*

```
0 & 0 === 0
0 & 1 === 0
1 & 1 === 1
```

Try going through w3c article: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp